# Open Source MRI Image Stacks

Tags: image-processing, data-sets

I'm working on a voxel-based modelling application and one of the features that I've implemented is a method to do a 3D mesh reconstruction from a series of 2D image slices (similar to an MRI).  I've got a basic brain scan image set that I've been working on, but ultimately I'd like to release a small demo example showing how to do the mesh reconstruction.  However, in order to do this I need the images to be legally open source so that I'm not distributing images that have copy right restrictions.  I've scoured the net trying to find a suitable image set but haven't been able to find anything.

Does anyone have any resources they could point me to that I could use for my application?

Comment: Maybe you can use data from the [Visible Human Project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visible_Human_Project). The license is not super open, but maybe they give you permission to use the data for your application.

Comment: You could also check http://opendata.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned before, you can try with the [Visible Human Project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visible_Human_Project).

You can also go with [3D Slicer sample data](http://www.slicer.org/publications/gallery), e.g., the [Knee Atlas](http://www.slicer.org/publications/item/view/1953) or the [Brain Atlas](http://www.slicer.org/publications/item/view/2037). Their terms are quite permissive:

> By downloading these data, you agree to acknowledge our contribution in any of your publications that result form the use of this atlas.

There is also [OpenfMRi](https://openfmri.org/dataset/), but you already had that answer in [opendata.SE](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/6661/open-source-mri-image-dataset).